# Monitoring the clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

The following class monitors the clipboard and raises an event whenever the contents change. The monitoring starts when the class is created and ends when `Dispose` is called.

To achieve this a [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#message_only) (a term that comes from the Win32 API) is created using an instance of [`HwndSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndsource) class (since I am using WPF). The window's handle is then registered via `AddClipboardFormatListener` to receive a message whenever the clipboard changes. The window's messages are processed by `WndProc` which raises the event when the [`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate) message comes.

In other solutions for monitoring the clipboard I saw this was done on the actual main window of the application, but I wanted to separate the logic of monitoring the clipboard form the View and keep a clean MVVM. In an application I would instantiate the `ClipboardMonitor` in the ViewModel.

I am interested if there may be any hidden pitfalls where this approach may go wrong.

```
public sealed class ClipboardMonitor : IDisposable
{
    private static class NativeMethods
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Places the given window in the system-maintained clipboard format listener list.
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the given window from the system-maintained clipboard format listener list.
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Sent when the contents of the clipboard have changed.
        /// </summary>
        public const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;

        /// <summary>
        /// To find message-only windows, specify HWND_MESSAGE in the hwndParent parameter of the FindWindowEx function.
        /// </summary>
        public static IntPtr HWND_MESSAGE = new IntPtr(-3);
    }

    private HwndSource hwndSource = new HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, NativeMethods.HWND_MESSAGE);

    public ClipboardMonitor()
    {
        hwndSource.AddHook(WndProc);
        NativeMethods.AddClipboardFormatListener(hwndSource.Handle);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NativeMethods.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(hwndSource.Handle);
        hwndSource.RemoveHook(WndProc);
        hwndSource.Dispose();
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == NativeMethods.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
        {
            OnClipboardContentChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the clipboard content changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler OnClipboardContentChanged;
}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) and [Implementing a Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) pages on MSDN.

Comment: Please do not change the code in your question after answers have been posted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.

Comment: @Mast I do not understand the edit term -> terminal (The meaning of 'term': a word or phrase that has an exact meaning). Enlighten me please.

Comment: As it's currently stated, it reads like the message-only window is a Win32 terminal. If it isn't, consider re-writing that part of your question to remove ambiguity. Make sure you don't invalidate any answers in the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks fine except for two points:

- a `Dispose()` method should never throw an exception but yours will likely throw one if it is called twice. This can be avoided by having a `private bool disposed` variable which is checked by an `if` condition.
- an event based method `OnXXX` is usually either `private` or `protected` and used to actually raise the event. A simple rename to `ClipboardChanged` will be sufficient to handle that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Looks good. My comments:

1. The `?` C# 6 syntax for null checking not protect you from case that between the null check and the `Invoke`, your handler can be null. 
   **Update:** As Dan Lyons wrote, this is not true. Thanks for the comment Dan, it helped me to answer my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535000/call-instead-of-callvirt-in-case-of-the-new-c-sharp-6-null-check/34535348#34535348).
2. About the `Dispose`, if your monitor supposed to be a thread safe, you need yo add the private flag like Heslacher wrote and do the disposed check in a thread safe manner.
3. Your `IDisposable` implementation is incomplete. what if the user of your monitor will not call `Dispose`?
4. `AddClipboardFormatListener` and `RemoveClipboardFormatListener` can return false, i.e. the operation failed. You need to handle these cases. 
   [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033(v=vs.85).aspx)

I like the usage of `HwndSource` instead of creating an hidden window and use its handle.

Comment: Point 1 is untrue.  Event handlers are a specific case called-out for use with the new `?.` operator: [New Features in C# 6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx).  The underlying implementation creates a temp variable so the original object is only referenced one time.

Comment: @DanLyons thanks for this. I checked it in the cil code but not on event handlers so I missing the special behavior